# Unable to install "quickly" on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10

Tags: apt, software-installation, ubuntu-touch, quickly

When running:

```
sudo apt-get install quickly
```

To install `quickly` I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package quickly
```

Why the error and how can I install it then?

Comment: Did you run sudo apt-get update  first?

Comment: Step It also I have tried but still can not

Comment: You are the 2nd today: http://askubuntu.com/q/713146/367444 .

Answer (score 2):

There is no release of quickly package in Ubuntu 15.10.
You can see here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+source/quickly
Try any other version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There are no quickly or quickly-ubuntu-template packages in Ubuntu 16.04.

An  alternative software to Quickly is [Illumination Software Creator](https://github.com/jsebean/IlluminationSoftwareCreator). Version 6 of this software (the latest version) is released as a Debian package under a GPLv2 license. Illumination Software Creator allows you to easily create apps using a drag and drop interface and export it to multiple platforms.

Comment: Is there any alternatives?