# Where does "The program '<package>' is currently not installed." get its program list from?

Tags: apt, package-management, gnome-terminal

When running the command `quickly` I get this output:

```
The program 'quickly' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install quickly
```

However when running:

```
apt-cache policy quickly
```

I just get:

```
N: Unable to locate package quickly
```

So therefore as the package `quickly` isn't in the repositories, where is the thing which tells me how to install a not currently installed program when I type a command that would belong to it getting its list of applications from? How does it get its list of programs and where from? Even if this is just an error, it reveals some of the workings of this program as it shows that it's not just looking at the package list which is downloaded with `sudo apt-get update`, otherwise it would know that the program does not exist. Also, is this just built-in functionality in `gnome-terminal` or is the thing responsible for the helpful message a separate application which can be uninstalled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc` you'll find some commands which ultimately define the bash function `command_not_found_handle`. Then `man bash` tells us that this command is invoked when a non-existing command is typed in. On my machine, the handle invokes `/usr/lib/command-not-found` as a python script. This again leads into `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py` which seems to invoke `apt-get` or `aptitute` (search for the two in the file).

Comment: So why is there this error with `quickly`? Just the datebase not updated properly or something?

Comment: Hmm, I am on a Linux Mint currently and when I run `apt-cache policy quickly` I get a nice output for `quickly`. So I guess it is some db mismatch. There is some talk about `db` and `BinaryDatabase` in the python program, but I am not into it enough to immediately see whether and when this is updated.

Comment: Well, are the Linux Mint repositories the same as the Ubuntu ones?

Comment: Well, if it just stays like this for ever I'll file a bug report...

Comment: No, Mint has its own repos, but it is based on Ubuntu. But I now logged into a machine with Ubuntu 14.04 and the policy command returns an installation candidate 12.08.1 there just fine.