# Unable to install Quickly on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, quickly

Can't install Quickly with `sudo apt-get install quickly quickly-ubuntu-template` this command.
It's showing

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package quickly
E: Unable to locate package quickly-ubuntu-template
```

What to do now?

I saw that [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713140/unable-to-install-quickly-on-ubuntu-gnome-15-10) but I am confused whether it is also not available for 16.04.