# What is the status of Ubuntu Quickly? Is it still developed?

Tags: application-development

I'm trying to look into Ubuntu Quickly, but the information seems really outdated, 2010. Is the project still on? What is the official page I can download it from?

Is there a similar tool in .deb packages I can use to create my applications? (or rather learn to create them)

Comment: Quickly is dead.  It was removed in 2015 because it is deprecated, unmaintained, and uses old and obsolete tech.  (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly/+bug/1494345)  There is nowhere to download it from as a result.  As for *creating* your applications, that's a very wide/vague discussion topic and without more details about your application(s) it is not going to be possible to narrow down the answer of "what tools can i use to create my applications"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install quickly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818048/how-to-install-quickly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install "quickly" on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713140/unable-to-install-quickly-on-ubuntu-gnome-15-10)